# Quotient space not the same as the original space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I am trying to understand why quotient space is not the same as the original space. Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ be its vector subspace. If I define $a+W:=\{x=a+w; w\in W\}$ then the quotient space $V/W$ is a set the elements of which  are $a+W$ for each $a\in V$. $V/W$ is quotient space.

Now, my issue stems from this:
Let $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}$ be the base of $W$. I can then complement it to get a base of $V$: $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k,u_{k+1},\ldots,u_n\}$, but then an element of $a+W$ can be written: $\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i w_i +\sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_i u_i + \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i w_i = \sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha_i+\beta_i)w_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n\beta_i u_i$ which is just expression of any element of $V$ since $a$ is any element of $V$ and $V$ is a vector space, then there will be always such $\alpha_i,\,i=(1,\ldots k)$ and $\beta_i,\,i=(1\ldots k+1)$ to make a necessary element of $V$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I am confused by your question; a quotient space and the original space are not the same because of some pretty fundamental reasons; their elements are not even the same type of object. It does not matter than an element of the set $a+W$ has a representation of a particular form. The elements of $V/W$ are sets, not vectors, and the elements of $a+W$ are vectors.

Comment: Expounding on what the commenter above said, the point is that in these quotient spaces elements of $w$ are identified with $0$. So if $a = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha w_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_i u_i \in V$, then $a + W =  \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha w_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_i u_i + W =  \sum_{i=k+1}^n \alpha_i u_i + W$ in the quotient space.

Comment: @mheldman I am a little confused, $a+W$ is a set of vectors $a+w$ for all $w\in W$, now if I vary $a$ so that $a\in V$ any vector from $V$, then I get a set with just more vectors. So $V/W$ is a set of sets $a+W$ which are not "expanded into vectors" and only thought of as sets regardless of their content? But if the quotient space is supposed to be a vector space, it has to have a basis, but if I am supposed to write a base, I need vectors, thus based on your notation, $\{u_{k+1} + W,\ldots,u_n+W\}$ is the basis?

Comment: I think what you're getting confused about is that $V = (V/W) \oplus W$. You can reconstruct $V$ from $W$ but that doesn't mean they're the same thing.

Comment: Remember that $w+W=W$ for all $w\in W$ so $w_i+W=W$ for all of the basis elements $w_i$ of $W$.

Comment: @leosenko Yes, this is exactly right. Notice $a + w + W = a + W$ for any $a\in V$. In fact, what's really going on with $V/W$ is an equivalence relation where vectors $u, v\in V$ are considered to be equivalent if $u = v + w$ for some $w\in W$. The notation $a + W$ for the equivalence classes of $V/W$ suggests that we 'mod out' by elements of $W$, that is, we expand $a$ in a basis w.r.t. $V$ and throw out the components which are in $W$. Notice that there is a canonical identification between $V/W$ and the subspace of $W$ given by $\text{span}\{u_{k+1},...,u_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the way you interpreted vectors in $V/W$. By definition, the quotient space $V/W$ is the set of all **affine subsets** of $V$ parallel to $U$:

$$
V/U=\{v+U: v\in V\}.
$$

So the vectors in $V/U$ are affine subsets which are not vectors in $V$ anymore.

Let me quote an example from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*:

> If $U$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the origin, then $\mathbb{R}^3/U$ is the set of all lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parallel to $U$.

In this case, the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3/U$ are lines not points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Would be good to fix the typos.